# jquery ui autocomplete ajax not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to use jquery autocomplete with an ajax source returning a json response as follows

```
    {"Places":[{"PlaceId":"LOND-sky","PlaceName":"London","CountryId":"UK-sky","RegionId":"","CityId":"LOND-sky","CountryName":"United Kingdom"},{"PlaceId":"LHR-sky","PlaceName":"London Heathrow","CountryId":"UK-sky","RegionId":"","CityId":"LOND-sky","CountryName":"United Kingdom"},{"PlaceId":"LGW-sky","PlaceName":"London Gatwick","CountryId":"UK-sky","RegionId":"","CityId":"LOND-sky","CountryName":"United Kingdom"},{"PlaceId":"STN-sky","PlaceName":"London Stansted","CountryId":"UK-sky","RegionId":"","CityId":"LOND-sky","CountryName":"United Kingdom"},{"PlaceId":"LTN-sky","PlaceName":"London Luton","CountryId":"UK-sky","RegionId":"","CityId":"LOND-sky","CountryName":"United Kingdom"},{"PlaceId":"LCY-sky","PlaceName":"London City","CountryId":"UK-sky","RegionId":"","CityId":"LOND-sky","CountryName":"United Kingdom"}]}
```

My code configuring jquery ui autocomplete is as follows

```
 $( "#originplace" ).autocomplete({
source: function( request, response ){
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
data: { query: request.query},
url: "/myurl.php",

success: function( data ) {

        response( $.map( data.Places, function( item ) {
            return {
                label: item.PlaceName,
                value: item.PlaceId
            }
        }));
        }  
}); 
}
});
```

It makes the request but does nothing with the response, I suspect my map function is wrong?
Advice much appreciated.

Comment: Find out what `console.log(data)` on `complete` handler returns - maybe it's an error

Comment: can you check whether ajax request is completed successfully... use the network tab of browser console to check the ajax request and response

Comment: the ajax request is completed successfully, I cut and paste that response from console network tab

Comment: `does nothing with the response` so dropdown doesn't appear?

Comment: yeah no dropdown appears, no error messages in console

Comment: Check you CSS. Maybe it appear, buy you can't see it. Your code is ok. http://plnkr.co/edit/JCsdysCa17xWCpWqRHYP?p=preview

Comment: it's not their the dom doesn't change